# url safe base64 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, base64, message-digest

Is MySQL's TO_BASE64 URL safe? Using java, I can write the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "SomeText";
        byte[] input = text.getBytes();
        // url safe base64
        // How do I do this in MySQL?
        // I tried mysql> SELECT TO_BASE64('SomeText'); but it does not seem to return url safe output
        Base64 base64 = new Base64(-1, null, true);
        input = base64.encode(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the docs, this is what I ended up doing:

Replace ‘+’ with '-'

Replace ‘/‘ with '_'

Remove trailing '='

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '=' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('SHA-1', TO_BASE64('SomeText')), '+', '-'), '/', '_')) AS input;
```